# Javafx Task Bar Icon - Issue

Tags: ubuntu, javafx, icons

In my Ubuntu machine , I have build my application using Javafx . But it displays the "Question Mark" not even the default cup symbol.Here How to set it using any external jars. Javafx Icon setting is still a bug since 2012.

Comment: Specifically the image is not displayed when the scene is set to stage.Before setting scene it works fine.

Comment: In the past I've created .desktop files to have an icon for JavaFX programs as they don't have an embedded icon.

Comment: If we use .desktop file to have icon .That display only during the execution of .desktop but once javaFX application started again the question mark displays.

Comment: @M.leRutte , How make an for JavaFX application using .desktop file.Is there anyway to display throughout the JavaFX execution. I am using script file to execute my JavaFX Application.In script ,I am building classpath and other required for execution.